# False proof $m = 1$ for any $m$

Tags: arithmetic, fake-proofs

Is it possible to find a fake proof that results in $$ 1 = m, $$ where $m$ is any number you chose?

The idea is to find a generalization to this fallacy:

> \begin{align}a &= b\\
> &\Downarrow\\
> a^2 - b^2 &= ab - b^2\\
> (a+b) (a-b) &= b (a-b)\\
> a+b &= b\\
> 2b &= b \\
> 2 &= 1 \end{align}

You can use division by zero or anything a little bit elaborated you can think of.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I believe there is a tacit implication from one line to the next, i.e., $a=b\implies a^2-b^2=ab-b^2\implies(a+b)(a-b)=b(a-b)$ etc. The first two implications are logically correct, as is the fourth (since $a=b$ implies $a+b=2b$). The fatal flaw, of course, occurs at the third step. But the final implication is also flawed, since $2b=b$ does not imply $2=1$ unless it's been established that $b\not=0$.

Comment: The idea @MauroALLEGRANZA is to assume you can divide by zero and see what interesting things you find, even if we all know it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $2=1$, you can prove using induction that $$\forall n\in\mathbb N,\,n=1.$$

Indeed, it is true for $1$ and also for $2$ by assumption. Assume that it's true for a certain $n>2$.

\begin{align}
n+1&=n-1+2\\
&=n-1+1\\
&=n\\
&=1.
\end{align}

**Edit:**

Another method which looks like a real generalisation of your given proof as follows: let $n\in\mathbb N$. We have:

\begin{align}
a&=b\\
a^n-b^n&=ab^{n-1}-b^n\\
(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-1-k}&=b^{n-1}(a-b)\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-1-k}&=b^{n-1}\\
nb^{n-1}&=b^{n-1}\\
n&=1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Let $a=b$.

Then 
\begin{align}a^m-b^m&=a^m-b^m \\
a^m-b^m&=ab^{m-1}-b^m \\
(a-b)(a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}b+...+b^{m-1})&=(a-b)b^{m-1} \\
a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}b+...+b^{m-1}&=b^{m-1}\\
mb^{m-1}&=b^{m-1}\\
m&=1\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $m$ be an arbitrary number and $x= \frac{m+1}{2}$.

Then we have
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{m+1}2\\
2x&=m+1\\
2x(m-1)&=(m+1)(m-1)\\
2xm-2x&=m^2-1\\
x^2+2xm-2x&=x^2+m^2-1\\
x^2-2x+1&=x^2-2xm+m^2\\
(x-1)^2&=(x-m)^2\\
x-1&=x-m\\
-1&=-m\\
m&=1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove that, for every positive integers $m$ and $n$, we have $m=n$; in particular, for every positive integer $m$, we have $m=1$.

We do it by induction on $\max(m,n)$ in the form “if $\max(m,n)=k$, then $m=n$”.

The base case, $\max(m,n)=1$ is trivial.

Suppose the statement holds when $\max(m,n)=k$ and take $m,n$ such that $\max(m,n)=k+1$. Then $\max(m-1,n-1)=k$, so by the induction hypothesis we get that $m-1=n-1$, hence $m=n$.

(Taken from “What is Mathematics?” by R. Courant and H. Robbins.)